# How do we operate with multiple Cassandra setups in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have two different Cassandra setups on two different machines. I am trying to read data from one machine, process it using Spark and then write the result into the second setup. I am using spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10. When I try to use javaFunctions.writeBuilder, it allows me to specify keyspace and table name, but the Cassandra host is fetched from the Spark Context. Is there a way to write data into a Cassandra setup other than one mentioned in Spark Context? How do we override this default setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code :

```
SparkConf confForCassandra = new SparkConf().setAppName("ConnectToCassandra")
                .setMaster("local[*]")
                .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "<cassandraHost>");

CassandraConnector connector = CassandraConnector.apply(confForCassandra);

javaFunctions(rdd).writerBuilder("keyspace", "table", mapToRow(Table.class)).withConnector(connector).saveToCassandra();
```